# I'm not sure how to get these values given in different classes to connect to each other in Javafx for a GUI I'm making

Tags: java, javafx

This is Javafx and I am making a GUI with multiple classes.

Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AutoLoanCalculator extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          launch(args);
       }
    
    
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        
        PaymentSection section1 = new PaymentSection();
        LoanTermSection section2 = new LoanTermSection();
        FinancingSection section3 = new FinancingSection();
        OptionsSection section4 = new OptionsSection();
        
        Button calc = new Button("Calculate");
        Button reset = new Button("Reset");
        Button exit = new Button("Exit");
        
        GridPane comboGrid = new GridPane();
        comboGrid.add(section1, 0, 0);
        comboGrid.add(section2, 1, 0);
        comboGrid.add(section3, 0, 1);
        comboGrid.add(section4, 1, 1);
        comboGrid.add(calc, 0,2);
        comboGrid.add(reset, 1,2);
        comboGrid.add(exit, 2,2);
        
        HBox combo = new HBox();
        combo.getChildren().add(comboGrid);
        
        calc.setOnAction(event ->{
            
            Double basePrice = Double.parseDouble(section3.getPriceNum());
            Double downPayment = Double.parseDouble(section3.getDownPayNum());
            Double taxRate = Double.parseDouble(section3.getTaxNum()) / 100;
            Double optionPrice = section4.getCost();
            Double interestRate = section2.getRate() / 100;
            int loanTermMonths = section2.getMonth();
            
            //calculates the values of rate and total sales tax
            double rate = interestRate/12;
            double salesTaxAmt = (basePrice - downPayment + optionPrice) * taxRate;
            
            Double totalLoanAmt = basePrice - downPayment + optionPrice + salesTaxAmt;
            Double monthPayment = totalLoanAmt * (rate * Math.pow(1 + rate, loanTermMonths)) / (Math.pow(1 + rate, loanTermMonths) - 1);
            Double totalPayment = monthPayment * loanTermMonths + downPayment;
            
            //section1.setLoanNum(String.format("%.2f", totalLoanAmt));
            
            System.out.println(basePrice);
            System.out.println(downPayment);
            System.out.println(taxRate);

        });
        
        reset.setOnAction(event ->{
            section1.reset();
            section2.reset();
            section3.reset();
            section4.reset();
        });
        
        exit.setOnAction(event ->{
            primaryStage.close();
        });
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(combo);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Auto Loan Calculator");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

//I call this section 1

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class PaymentSection extends GridPane{

    private Label payInfo;
    private Label loanAmount;
    private Label monthlyPayment;
    private Label totalPayment;
    private Label loanNum;
    private Label monthNum;
    private Label totalNum;
    private String loanInt;
    private String monthInt;
    private String totalInt;
    
    public PaymentSection () {
        payInfo = new Label("Payment Information");
        loanAmount = new Label("Total Loan Amount: $ ");
        monthlyPayment = new Label("Monthly Payment: $ ");
        totalPayment = new Label("Total Payment: $ ");
        
        loanNum = new Label();
        monthNum = new Label();
        totalNum = new Label();
        
        
        
        loanNum.setText("0.0");
        monthNum.setText("0.0");
        totalNum.setText("0.0");
    
        
        add(payInfo,0,0);
        add(loanAmount,0,1);
        add(monthlyPayment,0,2);
        add(totalPayment,0,3);
        add(loanNum,1,1);
        add(monthNum,1,2);
        add(totalNum,1,3);
        setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" + 
                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                "-fx-border-color: black;");
        }
    

    public String setLoanNum(String string) {
        return loanInt;
    }
    
    public void reset() {
        loanNum.setText("0.0");
        monthNum.setText("0.0");
        totalNum.setText("0.0");
    }
    
}
```

//I call this section 3

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class FinancingSection extends GridPane{

    private Label finance;
    private Label price;
    private Label tax;
    private Label downPay;
    private TextField priceNum;
    private TextField taxNum;
    private TextField downPayNum;
    private String priceInt;
    private String downPayInt;
    private String taxInt;
    

    public FinancingSection() {
        
        LoanTermSection term = new LoanTermSection();
        term.getRate();
        
        finance = new Label("Fianancing Information");
        price = new Label("Base Price: $ ");
        downPay = new Label("Down Payment: $ ");
        tax = new Label("Sales Tax: % ");
        
        priceNum = new TextField("0.0");
        downPayNum = new TextField("0.0");
        taxNum = new TextField("7.0");
        
        priceInt = priceNum.getText();
        downPayInt = downPayNum.getText();
        taxInt = taxNum.getText();
        
        add(finance,0,0);
        add(price,0,1);
        add(downPay,0,2);
        add(tax,0,3);
        add(priceNum,1,1);
        add(downPayNum,1,2);
        add(taxNum,1,3);
        setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" + 
                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                "-fx-border-color: black;");
        
        
    }
    
    public String getPriceNum() {
        return priceInt;
    }
    public void setPriceNum(String newPriceNum) {
        priceInt = newPriceNum;
    }
    
    public String getDownPayNum() {
        return downPayInt;
    }
    public void setDownPayNum(String newDownPay) {
        downPayInt = newDownPay;
    }
    
    public String getTaxNum() {
        return taxInt;
    }
    public void setTaxNum(String newTax) {
        taxInt = newTax;
    }
    
    public void reset() {
        priceNum.setText("0.0");
        downPayNum.setText("0.0");
        taxNum.setText("7.0");
    }
    
}
```

The issue is that I can't get basePrice, downPayment and taxRate to be set - I can't get them from their values set in section 3 code: I thought to use setters and getters but it seems to not work and I'm not sure why or how to fix it.- maybe it has something to do with my values I'm setting them as - not sure really.
As for section 1 I can't get it to print - which I'm assuming is the same issue as section 3. So mainly I just need help with section 3's values being fetched.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Orthogonal, but I suggest to just use the section names instead of numbers, e.g. instead of `PaymentSection section1`, use `PaymentSection payment` (or `PaymentSection paymentSection`), it will probably be easier to read and maintain then.  You could also refactor to use [MVC](https://edencoding.com/mvc-in-javafx/), e.g. separate `PaymentSection` into `PaymentView` and `Payment` classes and bind the `Payment` model class properties with the `PaymentView` UI properties. The MVC approach is more abstract and complex and you may not really need it for this app, just something to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `getText()` on the text fields at the time you retrieve the values. So, for example,

```
public class FinancingSection extends GridPane{

    // ...

    public String getPriceNum() {
        return priceNum.getText();
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can probably get rid of the `priceInt` variables,  etc., and you probably *should* get rid of the set methods in `FinancingSection` which you're not using.

The set methods that you are using, in `PaymentSection`, should update their corresponding labels, e.g.

```
public class PaymentSection extends GridPane{

    // ...

    public void setLoanNum(String string) {
        loanNum.setText(string) ;
    }

    // ...

}
```